# How to implement multi-part / sub commands in Spring Shell?

Tags: spring-shell

I am using Spring Shell 3.0.0 to implement a command line application.  The application deals with several types of objects and has several commands for each type of object, for example:

- `list-foos`
- `list-bars`
- `describe-foo XYZ`

To improve usability, I would like to change the syntax to

- `foo list`
- `bar list`
- `foo describe XYZ`

I understand that commands can be grouped and am using this functionality, which improves the help text, but as far as I can tell doesn't do anything beyond that.

I could implement this as separate top level `foo` and `bar` commands that take the subcommand as a positional parameter, but am looking for a better way.  For example, I'd like to be able to define each subcommand as its own method (e.g. using `@ShellMethod`) so it can have its own parameters, help text, availability, etc.

The documentation implies there is support for sub commands:

```
A command in a spring-shell structure is defined as an array of commands. This yields a structure
similar to the following example:
command1 sub1
command2 sub1 subsub1
command2 sub2 subsub1
command2 sub2 subsub2
```

But I haven't been able to figure out how to make this work.  Curious if this is possible and if so how to set it up?  Ideally, I'd like typing `foo` to show a list of subcommands, `help foo` to show help on those commands, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by defining the command in the methods annotation like this :

```java
@Command(group = "Foo commands")
public class Foo {
    @Command(command = "foo list")
    public void list() {
        ...
    }

    @Command(command = "foo description")
    public void description() {
        ...
    }
}
```

It works with `@Command` but not tried with `@ShellMethod` (I think it will be the same).

Not really the "better" way to do this, a global prefix command on the class might be easier to maintain, but for now I don't know any other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Command` annotation can be used at the type level. In your case, you could annotate a `Foo` class with the `@Command` annotation:

```java
@Command(command = "foo", group = "Foo Commands")
public class Foo {

    @Command(command = "describe", description = "Describe XYZ that is passed")
    public String describe(@Option(longNames = {"xyz-arg"}, required = true) String xyzArg) {
        return "Hello world " + xyzArg;
    }

    @Command(command = "list", description = "List all foos")
    public String list() {
        return "Listy McListface";
    }
}
```

###### Command annotation

The `@Command` annotation on the class provides a "parent" level command. `@Command` annotations on the methods in that class will need to be called using the class-level and method-level commands (E.g. `foo list`) - see [Spring Shell annotation documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/reference/commands/registration/annotation.html).

The `group` attribute is the name of the group that will appear when the `help` command is run. The output of `help` will show all methods in the `Foo` class annotated with `@Command` as well.

###### Positional arguments

As of Spring Shell 3.2.2, the Spring Shell documentation suggests the way to add positional arguments is to use the `CommandRegistration` class - see ([Spring Shell positional arguments documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/reference/options/positional.html)).

Instead, the `describe` method in my example uses the `@Option` annotation on a method parameter which means it should be called using `foo describe --xyz XYZ`. However, calling it using `foo describe XYZ` as stated in your question also works as expected.

###### Sample output

[image: output of running help and foo commands]